# Migrating data from MySQL(rdbms) to Neo4j database

Tags: neo4j

I wanted to migrate data from MySQL to neo4j database. So how can i start with. I do not want to use any ETL tools like Talend. Directly if i want to migrate the data from any of the relational database to neo4j , how can i do it? Do i need to use any JDBC drivers? 
Suppose say in my MySQL database, i have a table called `emp` and data as below:

`companyname, domain,head, manager, employee
abc ,service, Adam, Taylor, Smith
abc ,service, John, sufi, sham
abc , industrial,George, Ralf, maxin
abc,industrial,George,susen,leena
xyz, service,josaf,Rihan, dardy`

So if i want to migrate this data into neo4j, how can i do it? How data will be seen in neo4j? Do i need to explicitly define the nodes and relationships to migrate the data ? If yes, how this can be done?

Thanks,
 Shree

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to do would be to model your graph irrespective of where the data is coming from. I don't know your use case but I imagine you'd have nodes for company, domain, person and relations between persons and companies or persons and persons (manager etc.)

Once you've got your graph model in place, then you can simply read from MySQL, transform the data to represent your nodes/relations and write it to Neo4j.

Have a look at http://neo4j.com/blog/data-migration-between-mysql-and-neo4j/ for an example on how this worked for my use case.